# Harddrive slows down, sata errors on boot

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, sata

Full rundown: This is not a new drive, I've had it for a while as an ntfs drive and I decided to install it into my linux server and switch it to ext4 filesystem.

- I partitioned the 4tb drive using `fdisk` to (g) make a gpt table and (n) create a single partition.
- I started copying files over to it with `rsync` and it was going at normal speeds (130-150MB/S).
- About somewhere near the end of the `rsync` (copying nearly 3tb of data) it starts slowing down to 2MB/s or less.
- I restart the server and notice it's taking longer than usual to reboot, so I connect a display and get shown a bunch of sata related errors on the device.
- I enter maintenance mode using root login and run `mke2fs` on the device `/dev/sdd` and here is the output. Can someone help me understand it?

  ```
  ata5.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x2000000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
  ata5.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
  ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ata5.00: cmd 60/08:c8:00:be:c0/00:00:d1:01:00/40 tag 25 ncq 4096 in res 41/40:08:00:be:c0/00:00:d1:01:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
  ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
  ata5.00: error: { UNC }
  end_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 7814036992
  Buffer I/O error on device sdd, logical block 976754624
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are all symptoms (Sudden speed drop, I/O error logs, long wait to boot) of a failing drive. Depending on how much use it got previously, it may have only become apparent after doing such a large file transfer.

It would be a good idea to check the output from `smartctl` to see whether any errors are logged against the drive. I would usually recommend backing up, but in this scenario it sounds like you're starting fairly freshly with the drive so this may not be a requirement.

It may also be worth checking the SATA cable, perhaps swapping for another one, as these can on occasion fail, and trying a different power source if possible.

It's a good idea to check the `SMART` status of the drive and run a thorough test across it, but I am confident that regardless of the result, if you try another cable and it hasn't helped, you will need to replace the drive.

Comment: Will go and check these and report back. Gotta go dig out a spare sata cable too. I also have a feeling it's a failing drive, it's a seagate if that's any indication. I've started swtiching over to hitachi which I've heard have way less failure rates than Seagate and WD.

Comment: @danielr Hard to blame any particular manufacturer, I've experienced failures from them all! These things happen unfortunately

Comment: Started up the machine with a new sata/power cables. It starts ticking, so I turn off the machine, switch back to the original cables, still ticking. You were right, it  was a failed drive :(. Looks like I'm going to the local pc parts store tomorrow! At least I have all my data safe so nothing too bad happened.

Comment: @danielr Sorry to hear that, but at least it has happened this early on and not when you've established a system on it. Best of luck..!

Comment: 99% of the time, when you see "I/O error" in reference to a disk, it's a hardware problem. If you're lucky, it's just a bad or loose cable. Otherwise, it's time to replace the disk. SMART can be a useful diagnostic, but it's not perfect. I've seen cases where SMART says everything's fine and then the disk goes belly-up the next day.

Comment: Thanks for the input Rod, I'll know that for next time. Just to close this off, the hdd makes ticking sounds as I mentioned before. Three machines that I try to plug this drive into cause them to be unable to boot safely and forces them into their "recovery mode" (two linux-based and one windows 7). I've decided not to torture the drive anymore and file an rma with seagate as I'm still within the warranty period thankfully.